# How can I clean up my MediaPlayer after use?

Tags: android, button, onclick, media-player

Is this the correct way to use the MediaPlayer?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{


        MediaPlayer sound1, sound2, sound3, sound4;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            //Sound MediaPlayers
            sound1= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound1);
            sound2= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound2);
            sound3= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound3);
            sound4= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound4);

        }


    //sound onClick's 
    public void sound1(View view){
        sound1.start();
    }
    public void sound2(View view){
        sound2.start();
    }
    public void sound3(View view){
        sound3.start();
    }
    public void sound4(View view){
        sound4.start();
    }

}
```

I have to clean up the MediaPlayer, but I don't know how I can do that.
I know that I have to use `sound1.release()` but it doesn't work if I write:

```
public void sound1(View view){
            sound1.start();
            sound1.release();
        }
```

Please give me an example.

Comment: You should only create a single MediaPlayer instance and load the sound you want to play at the appropriate time.

Comment: @BladeCoder like this? http://pastebin.com/EhdMt3sB

Comment: Yes for example. But if a previous MediaPlayer instance still exists, you must properly stop it and release it.

Comment: That is the point, I don't now how to do this. I'm new at Android Studio :)

Comment: @AaronWaller , in this case, it is not IDE (Android Studio) related but simply Android related. Long story short, refactor your code first to be using only one instance of MediaPlayer instead of 4 and then we can help you better

Comment: @user3793589 I know how I can clean up the MediaPlayer with only 1 sound. But I dont know how to do it with more than 1.

Comment: @AaronWaller Well, check the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the work for you.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{


    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    //sound onClick's 
    public void sound1(View view){
        cleanUpMediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound1);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    public void sound2(View view){
        cleanUpMediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound2);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    public void sound3(View view){
        cleanUpMediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound3);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    public void sound4(View view){
        cleanUpMediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound4);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    public void cleanUpMediaPlayer(){
        if(mediaPlayer != null) {
            if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
            }
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to call release() too

Comment: @BladeCoder, Right. Edited my answer.